# Spring boot jpa query parameter

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jwt, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have an issue with add parameter in JPA Query
My OrderEntity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "orderbill")
public class OrderEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;
    
    @Column(name = "timebought")
    private Date timebought;
    
    @Column(name = "totalcost")
    private Float totalCost;
    
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    
    @Column(name = "ratenum")
    private Integer rateNum;
    
    @Column(name = "ratetext")
    private String rateText;
    
    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productid")
    private ProductEntity products;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customeremail")
    // @JsonBackReference
    private PersonEntity customers;
    
    public OrderEntity() {
        super();
    }
    
    public OrderEntity(OrderDTO order) {
        super();
        this.id = order.getId();
        this.quantity = order.getQuantity();
        this.timebought = order.getTimebought();
        this.totalCost = order.getTotalCost();
        this.address = order.getAddress();
        this.rateNum = order.getRateNum();
        this.rateText = order.getRateText();
        this.status = order.isStatus();
        this.products = new ProductEntity(order.getProducts());
        this.customers = new PersonEntity(order.getCustomers());
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public ProductEntity getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    
    public void setProducts(ProductEntity products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
    
    public PersonEntity getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }
    
    public void setCustomers(PersonEntity customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }
    
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        if (quantity < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantity must not below zero");
        }
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    
    public Date getTimebought() {
        return timebought;
    }
    
    public void setTimebought(Date timebought) {
        this.timebought = timebought;
    }
    
    public float getTotalCost() {
        return totalCost;
    }
    
    public void setTotalCost(float totalCost) {
        if (totalCost < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Total must not below zero");
        }
        this.totalCost = totalCost;
    }
    
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    public int getRateNum() {
        return rateNum;
    }
    
    public void setRateNum(int rateNum) {
        if (rateNum < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rate number must not below zero");
        }
        this.rateNum = rateNum;
    }
    
    public String getRateText() {
        return rateText;
    }
    
    public void setRateText(String rateText) {
        this.rateText = rateText;
    }
    
    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    
    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    
}
```

I have a repository like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Integer> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value="select o from OrderEntity o where o.customers.getEmail() = :email")
    List<OrderEntity> findByCustomers(@Param("email")String email);
}
```

And i use it

```java
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    @Autowired
    OrderRepository orderRepository;
    public List<OrderEntity> findOrderByCustomer(String email) {
        PersonEntity person = personService.getPerson(email);
        List<OrderEntity> orderList = orderRepository.findByCustomers(person.getEmail());
        if (orderList.isEmpty())
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException("Could not find any order bought by email: " + email);
        return orderList;
    }
```

But what i get is

```
Hibernate: select userentity0_.email as email1_1_, userentity0_.fullname as fullname4_1_, userentity0_.password as password6_1_, userentity0_.role as role8_1_ from persons userentity0_ where userentity0_.email=?
Hibernate: select userentity0_.email as email1_1_, userentity0_.fullname as fullname4_1_, userentity0_.password as password6_1_, userentity0_.role as role8_1_ from persons userentity0_ where userentity0_.email=?
```

When I test with Postman, it return 404
How do i know my param had add into query? I also can't run Debug. At first, it said i **absent absent line number information** But after i change jre1.8 to jdk1.8. It not show that message but also skip my breakpoint. Please help me

Comment: `nativeQuery` is the _last resort_ only when you can't express a query otherwise. You can eliminate the entire `@Query` and simply say `findByCustomersEmail`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I did that but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

To log SQL statements, you can use:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

To log parameters, you can use:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

If you're having trouble debugging, you can add a log instead, to see what "email" is (in addition to adding the trace logging configuration mentioned above.) I would suggest looking up documentation on debugging Spring Boot with the specific IDE you use.

Comment: my log didn't show up. I have a log4j.properties

Comment: I think your first answer is right. My end-point is incorrect, so it can't point to Controller. And it took half day to fix my debug on eclipse. Thank you so much